# cucumber + capybara = has_content? returns true everytime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, capybara, minitest

i'm using following:

```
minitest 5.3.5
cucumber 1.3.15
capybara 2.3.0
capybara_minitest_spec 1.0.2
rails 4.1.1
cucumber-rails 1.4.1
```

and my cucumber/capybara code

```
Then(/^I should see "(.*?)"$/) do |string|
  page.has_content?(string)
end
```

with any string, independent is it on the page or not returns true. I've tried to use     capybara_minitest_spec gem and my code becomes

```
Then(/^I should see "(.*?)"$/) do |string|
  page.must_have_content(string)
end
```

then i've got error

```
Then I should see "Test" # features/step_definitions/pages_steps.rb:9
  undefined method `assert_page_has_content' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  (eval):4:in `must_have_content'
  ./features/step_definitions/pages_steps.rb:10:in `/^I should see "(.*?)"$/'
  features/can_access_home.feature:7:in `Then I should see "Test"'
```

So strange. With save_and_open_page i see my page without any problems. Could you help me please to fix it?

PS: i'm using minitest but not rspec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed problem with following

```
Then(/^I should see "(.*?)"$/) do |string|
  assert page.has_content?(string)
end
```

Comment: Yep, you have to assert. Except there's no reason page is defined correctly here, and is nil when you use `page.must_have_content(string)`. Can you double check this second form does not work ?

Comment: undefined method `must_have_content' for #<Capybara::Session> (NoMethodError) :(((

Comment: Well, that changes from your initial error :) You probably have to include matchers somewhere in your cucumber setup. Anyway, using `assert` is just as fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Then(/^I should see "(.*?)"$/) do |string|
  page.has_content?(string)
end
```

This is not an assertion, this is a method that returns a boolean. Assertions throw exceptions, which is what makes test fail.

If you want to assert existence of your string, you have to use :

```
Then(/^I should see "(.*?)"$/) do |string|
  assert page.has_content?("Home#index")
end
```

`page.must_have_content` actually does the same thing, except your error says `page` is nil.

Comment: I've got 

       undefined method `expect' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0x007f85bd7d96d8> (NoMethodError)

for your last example

Comment: My bad, I don't know why I thought you were using rpsec. Well, first observation still stands, but there's a visit problem. Updating anwser.

Comment: Ok, we don't know why `page` was not defined the first time you tried to use `#must_have_content`. I still leave this answer for further reference as it explains you're supposed to assert your expectation rather than just returning a boolean.